# How can I add more than one tabbed page on one content page in xamarin forms?

Tags: forms, xamarin, tabbed, stacklayout

I have two different tabbed pages that I created, and the plan is to put them on one content page or single page, but I'm getting this error:

```
Error   XLS0503 A value of type 'HomeIncidentListTabbedPage' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'IList'.
```

Not sure how I would achieve this.

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="250"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  Grid.Row="0">
                    <Views:HomeTaskListTabbedPage/>
                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  Grid.Row="1">
                    <StackLayout HeightRequest="50" BackgroundColor="#004B21">
                        <Label Text="ACCIDENTS/ICIDENTS" TextColor="White" FontSize="Medium" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  Grid.Row="0">
                        <Views:HomeIncidentListTabbedPage />
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: "pages" in Forms are intended to be full screen UI elements.  You cannot have more than one onscreen at a time

Comment: thanks for ur  quick respond , @Jason , but how would  is there anyway where i can achieve  something like this  on xamarin forms

Comment: any refference or a  page to read on in case  can require  some custom renders  to do this ? Thanks  for ur help

Comment: you can simulate a tabbed interface using a Segmented control

Comment: Maybe Carousel View will be your need .https://xamarinhelp.com/carousel-view-xamarin-forms/ Otherwise, Shell contains the tab propery can be setted easily. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/introduction#shell-navigation-experience